# javascript function not working (TableFilter library)

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, web-applications

I'm trying to make a table in my web app filterable. The TableFilter library seems to be really good but I'm not able to make it work (only in the web app since it works with a simple html page).

this is the code of my page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Show Elements In Table Page</title>

    <script src="~/tableFilter/tablefilter.js"></script>
    <script src="~/tableFilter/tablefilter_all.js"></script>
    <script src="~/tableFilter/tablefilter_all_min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/tableFilter/tablefilter_min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="pageBody" onload="createTable(getLocalItem('selectedTable'), 'elementsTable');
    hideElement('loading'); 
    document.getElementById('tableName').innerHTML = getLocalItem('selectedTable');
    prova();">

    <h3 id="loading">loading...</h3>
    <div style="margin-left: 1em; margin-top: 1em;">
        <h3 id="tableName"></h3>
        <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id="elementsTable">
            <!--the table loads with the createTable() function-->
        </table>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        setFilterGrid("elementsTable");
        <!--this is not working-->
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the **createTable()** js function:

```
function createTable(tableName, tableId) {
    fetch(domain + urlParameters + tableName)
        .then(r => r.text())
        .then(j => JSON.parse(j))
        .then(o => {

            var cols = getVarNames(o);

            //header
            var tableHtml = "<thead><tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                tableHtml += "<th>" + cols[i] + "</th>";
            }
            tableHtml += "</tr></thead>";
            //body
            tableHtml += "<tbody><tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                    tableHtml += "<td>" + o[i][cols[j]] + "</td>";
                }
                tableHtml += "</tr>";
            }
            tableHtml += "</tbody>";

            //insertion in document
            document.getElementById(tableId).innerHTML = tableHtml;
        });
}

function getVarNames(list) {
    var columns = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var row = list[i];

        for (var k in row) {
            if ($.inArray(k, columns) == -1) {
                columns.push(k);
            }
        }
    }
    return columns;
}
```

**the table is loaded but it is not filterable. the script in the body seems to not recognize the table. how could i solve?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved creating my own query methods in javascript. maybe this could be helpful for someone.

```
var tableObject; //variable storing the json object form the api

    function createTable(tableName, tableId) {
    fetch(domain + urlParameters + tableName)
        .then(r => r.text())
        .then(j => JSON.parse(j))
        .then(o => {

            tableObject = o;
            //insert filtering variables

            var cols = getVarNames(tableObject);

            //header
            var tableHtml = "<thead><tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                tableHtml += "<th>" + cols[i] + "</th>";
            }

            //insert selection and filtering tools
            tableHtml += "<tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                tableHtml += "<td><textarea class=\"filter\" rows=\"1\" placeholder=\"input\" style=\"resize: none;\"></textarea></td>";
                //add some kind of tag matching the column -> maybe a class? or an id?
            }
            tableHtml += "</tr>";
            tableHtml += "</tr></thead>";

            //body
            tableHtml += "<tbody id=\"tableBody\"><tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < tableObject.length; i++) {
                if (objectIncludesFilters(tableObject[i], cols, getValuesFilters())) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                        tableHtml += "<td>" + tableObject[i][cols[j]] + "</td>";
                    }
                    tableHtml += "</tr>";
                }
            }
            tableHtml += "</tbody>";

            //insertion in document
            document.getElementById(tableId).innerHTML = tableHtml;
        });
}

function getVarNames(list) {
    var columns = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var row = list[i];

        for (var k in row) {
            if ($.inArray(k, columns) == -1) {
                columns.push(k);
            }
        }
    }
    return columns;
}

function getValuesFilters() {
    const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("filter");
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        var value = collection[i].value;
        values.push(value);
        if (value == null) {
            values.push("");
        }
    }
    return values;
}

function objectIncludesFilters(obj, cols, filters) {
    var result = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
        if (!obj[cols[i]].toLowerCase().includes(filters[i].toLowerCase())) {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: tableObject isn't necessary